# Is there any effective way to reduce error in HyperLogLog ( redis )?

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, redis, hyperloglog

In redis , we treat **hyperLogLog** as set to distinct elements.

As everyone knows, for each key, HLL consumes only 12kb memory and produces approximations with a standard error of 0.81%

Since I got so much elements to count. So here I wanna to lower the error occours by storing elements into multiple hll keys ( eg. "hll_key_%d" % (Element mod 1024) )

It's a effective way to lower the error in fact ? 
Or any other way to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. The error of HyperLogLogs can be assumed to be normally distributed, if the number of inserted elements is significantly larger than the number of registers which is 2^14 in the Redis implementation. If elements are equally sharded over multiple HyperLogLogs and the number of elements per HyperLogLog is still larger than the number of registers the total cardinality estimate obtained by summing up the cardinality estimates of all HyperLogLogs will have a smaller error.

The reason is that the sum of N independently and normally distributed numbers with mean M and standard error S will be normally distributed with mean N x M and standard error S x SQRT(N). Therefore the relative error changes from S / M to S x SQRT(N) / (N x M) = S / (M x SQRT(N)) which corresponds to a SQRT(N) improvement.

However, this sharding approach will not work for arbitrary numbers of HyperLogLogs. Once the partial cardinalities drop below the number of registers the assumption of normally distributed errors will be violated and the improvement of the estimation error will be smaller or even negligable.

Answer (score 0):

NO, you CANNOT lower the error by sharding keys into multiple HyperLogLogs. No matter how many HyperLogLogs you use, the error is always 0.81%.

There's no way to lower the error, unless you modify the source code.